# Retrieving data from database by using a combo box

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

I have a little semester project, I have a combo box connected to a database table, I want to code a button that shows the rest of the table when I choose a value from the combo box.
am using SQLEXPRESS Database in that project just might be helping.

I tried this code, but it didn't work for me, giving me the error

> incorrect syntax near ','.

```
 string Msg;
        Msg = m.RunDml(" Select * From Doctor Where DocName=" + txtName.Text + " , Gender='" + chk1.Text + "' , BirthDate='" + dtpBDate.Text + "' , Address='" + txtAddress.Text + "' , Salary='" + txtSalary.Text + "')");
        if (Msg == "ok")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Editing Successfully done! ");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Msg);
        }
```

and so the `ComboBox` for `DocID` code is:

```
    this.doctorTableAdapter.Fill(this.testdb_morgDataSet.Doctor);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. I am sorry to tell you but your question is most probably going to be closed soon. The reason, you did not show any own effort to provide a solution. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Have a nice day.

Comment: Please be specific, add suitable code snippets and the exact problem you are facing, do not ask for general solutions.

Comment: Okay, am sorry, i will edit the question.

Comment: The reason for this error is most probably that you forgot the single quotation marks `'` around `txtName.Text`. But to insert user input directly into your sql command is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com)! You should avoid this!

Comment: I STRONGLY recommend that you read up on parameterized queries, to avoid user data to interfer with your Query, both from a functional standpoint and from a security perspective (SQL injections)

Comment: may I reccommend using `String Interpolation` ?! It makes such things way easier to read. Here's an example: `$"My name is {name}"  => My name is Adam` see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/846566/What-s-new-in-Csharp-String-Interpolation for details.It is very nice when building SQL Querys.

Comment: @FeDe Using string interpolation is **not safe** for SQL queries, as they still leave you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i see what you mean but in this case... ? But please explain how `string query = "Select * From Doctor Where DocName='{txtName.Text}', Gender='{chk1.Text}' ,BirthDate='{dtpBDate.Text}' ,Address='{txtAddress.Text}' ,Salary='{txtSalary.Text}'";` is more vulnerable than `string query = "Select * From Doctor Where DocName=" + txtName.Text + " , Gender='" + chk1.Text + "' , BirthDate='" + dtpBDate.Text + "' , Address='" + txtAddress.Text + "' , Salary='" + txtSalary.Text + "';` Cause I cannot see that ...

Comment: @FeDe Say `txtName.Text` is `"' UNION ALL select * from users -- "`, then you can query the users table (maybe with some additional tricks to get the same number and relevant columns). All this is solved when using prepared statements (parameterized queries), as the values are correctly escaped (or sent separately).

Comment: @RenéVogt tried but didn't work also.

Comment: @JaggenSWE unfortunately, i don't know it, haven't studied it so far, but i will check for online courses about it, thanks

Comment: @MarkRotteveel didn't work too, still giving me the same error.

Comment: @FeDe can you explain more?

Comment: @M.Morgan I didn't provide a solution to your problem. But your problem (besides the lack of quotes around text, and the glaring security flaws) is that you use a comma to separate conditions instead of `and` or `or`.

Comment: The problem with inserting user input directly into your query instead of using parameterized queries is not only SQL injection. I guess your error arises from that too. And another point: you did not tell us what database system (with which sql dialect) you use... Maybe you should replace your commas with `AND`. I just realized that I never saw commas in a `WHERE` clause before.

Comment: @RenéVogt using SQL Server Data base, SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: The reason for your error is one stray `)` after your `select` statement and also using commas instead of `AND`. Also as others said you should always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I see the point when you say that creating a query directly from textboxes is unsafe. Still why should StringInterpolation more unsafe than `"Select * FROM ADC WHERE '" + textbox1.Text +"'";` since the lack of security is that you can insert anything in that textbox. But gernerally spoken isn't the output the same ?

Comment: @FeDe They are both equally unsafe, SQL (and the driver in C#) has features to solve exactly this problem: use them; don't replace one unsafe solution with another unsafe solution. SQL injection is probably still the number one cause for security leaks, even though the solution has been around for decades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The points about [SQL injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com) have been made in the comments and noelicus' answer.

The reason for your error seems to be that you use commas where you shoud use `AND` (or - less likely - `OR`). Commas are (afaik) not allowed in a `WHERE` clause. I just tried this with my SQL server and got the same error as you.

See [this MSDN documentation of the `WHERE` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) for more information.

So change your request to this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Doctor WHERE DocName='" + txtName.Text + "' AND Gender='" +
    chk1.Text + "' AND BirthDate='" + dtpBDate.Text + "' AND Address='" + 
    txtAddress.Text + "' AND Salary='" + txtSalary.Text + "'"
```

Don't forget the quotation marks around `txtName.Text` and to remove the superfluous closing parenthesis at the end.

**And please inform yourself about SQL injection vulnerabilities.** Note that your request will break as soon as you input a `'` in one of the textboxes.

Comment: Giving me error again.
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: sure. i just copied your request which contains a superfluous closing parenthesis. updated my answer.

Comment: as a tip for the future: it's often easier to _read_ the error message and check your request for that, to read the documentation for the features you use, and to test your request in a tool like sql management studio or your Ide than asking questions in a forum hoping that somebody else does all this for you. Plus: you learn more by finding out yourself.

Comment: Well, don't know what to say but the error changed this time, giving me an error and it is " Error converting data type varchar to numeric "

Comment: your `Salary` for example is probably a numeric data type but you try to insert the `string` from the text box....parse it to an `double` or `decimal` and remove the quotation marks....for _all numeric columns_... again: better use parameterized queries....last comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that the system is actually being quite helpful. If you look at the first comma in your SQL command it's after your `txtName.txt`, which you've forgotten to put in quotes (which I see you have done for your other text items).

So try:

```
" Select * From Doctor Where DocName='" + txtName.Text + "' , Gender='" + chk1.Text + "' , BirthDate='" + dtpBDate.Text + "' , Address='" + txtAddress.Text + "' , Salary='" + txtSalary.Text + "')"
```

Should you want to improve your project at a later date or write production code then you will want to look at preventing SQL injection. When starting out don't worry about it but keep it mind! ...
To prevent SQL Injection you would use parameters rather than directly putting user fields in your SQL query though, or somebody could use SQL injection to do bad things to your database (for example if the txtName.Text was set to `"'; Delete * FROM Doctor;"`...)

Comment: Little semester project. I think it will be okay for him/her to start from basics.

Comment: Tried but i didn't work, still giving me the same error.